# How can I prevent unused values in a JSON response from returning as null with Springfox in Java?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

For example, my Spring boot Java API was returning:

```
{
    "contact": "John Smith",
    "badgeNumber": "12345",
    "inProcess": true
}
```

Then I added [SpringFox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/) dependencies for Swagger and now all my API is returning:

```
{
    "contact": "John Smith",
    "badgeNumber": "12345",
    "supervisor": null,
    "inProcess": true,
    "employeeReference": null,
    "vacationDates": null
}
```

Everything in swagger is working smoothly, but I don't want these null fields to return.  They should be excluded from the response by default.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think below answer will be useful.
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147059/prevent-null-values-in-json-result-spring)

Comment: @Asanka I have tried this and it does not work.

Comment: @Asanka I have figured it out.  That answer was partially correct for my use case.  I had to include the @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) annotation at the class level, not at the ObjectMapper.